# Unable to detect Memory issue using BoundsChecker

Tags: c++, bounds-checker

recently we observed that our application server memory is increasing with some client API, in the end it leads to crash.

so we tried using boundschecker and it shows NO memory leak and leads to crash as memory is increasing ( private bytes are increasing ). verified in Process Explore of MS(sysinternals).

so is there any way to get how memory is allocated in sequence (function calls), or handle allocated in sequence. so we can get memory is increasing at this position.

we wants to capture all function calls from all threads. also we can't chnage too much code as it is thousnads lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't find any memory leak, it's very likely that you have a handle leak - you can check this even in Task Manager by selecting "Handle Count" in the list of columns. Process Explorer should be able to show you a list of open handles in your application. This may not be in sequence but it should give you an idea of what kind of resource is leaking - often, all the leaks originate from the same area of your application, which can accumulate over time and cause a crash.

Comment: yeah its looks to me also, but using MemoryValidator(http://www.softwareverify.com/cpp/memory/index.html), it didn't find any memory as well as handle leak till application is alive.